# Extra theme - header customization help

Tags: customization

Can anyone help with the customization of the header section for the Extra theme (Elegant Themes)? I would need customization for the desktop version only, the mobile/tablet version is just as needed.

Secondary navigation/top-header (desktop): 
It features links on the left and social media/search box on the right. What I would need instead is that this row contains links only. Internal links, aligned to the left and external links, aligned to the right. 
Main Header:
This should contain the logo to the left and the search box and social icons (aligned to the right). The main navigation links that are displayed (on desktop) to the right of the logo should instead be in a separate row underneath the logo. 
Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated!

Comment: what have you accomplished so far?

Comment: Ok, so I reworked what I need.

Comment: I reworked it. Re: Elegant Themes > Extra theme: I left the top-header (with secondary nav, social media, search box) and the main header (with primary nav and logo) as they are. I coded in a third menu underneath the main header to display categories. There are issues: 1.) When starting to scroll the 3rd menu overlaps the fixed main header. It should either be part of the fixed main header or disappear when scrolling (just like top header). 2.) The third menu needs to become part of the theme's mobile menu. How can I add it to Extra's mobile menu? Any advice? https://www.pixelpoise.com/demo2/